# Why Array.toString or Array.deepToString does not work?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I was testing out how to print arrays. I can use `for loop` to print it but when I am  trying to use `Arrays.toString` or `Arrays.deepToString` just not work. Here is an example

```
  package Week4;
  import java.util.Arrays; 
  public class prac2 {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     String[][] array = new String[][] { 
                { "Elem11", "Elem12", "Elem13" }, 
                { "Elem21", "Elem22", "Elem23" },
                { "Elem31", "Elwm32", "Elem33" } };
            System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array));
}
```

}

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
Arrays cannot be resolved

at Week4.prac2.main(prac2.java:14)
```

I am using JRE1.8.0_20. Is it something to do with the library? I am using eclipse.

Comment: The method names aren't capitalized. Try `deepToString` instead of `DeepToString`.

Comment: yeah i know the but the problem is (Arrays) is not recognized. its comes up with quick fixes

Comment: Did you add `import` statement for `java.util.Arrays`?

Comment: i just ran your code and it works fine. i just `import java.util.Arrays`

Comment: i cannot add the import statement. it says its not resolved. thats why i was wondering if its something to do with the library

Comment: Show us your full code and error massage you get.

Comment: Try not to ever assume your problem lies in the language or the library you are using. In programming, 99.99999999999% of the time the problem is user error.

Comment: @user2775042 try to download rt.jar then add it to build path

Comment: @Kerppag Thank you. that worked. If you  post it as an answer i can set it as the right answer and everybody can see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think it is with the IDE that you are using, it is not properly installed or incomplete packages.

```
1. i ran your code in my IDE

2. import java.util.Arrays;

3. since you still have error i press `ctrl` then hover to `import java.util.Arrays;` which leads me to the `Arrays.class`

4. look to the hierarchy of the packages and looked where it came from `rt.jar` which contains all of the compiled class files for the base Java Runtime environment.
```

Comment: Downloaded rt.jar and put into the build path. now it is working. Thanks